# Spring throw Bad Request if the request param not available in Controller method

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to restrict the list of allowed request parameters in my controller, so that if I get a request with an undefined parameter in the controller, it should return a **bad request**, but it returns `200 OK`.

I think that this one should be fixed on the framework level, but not in the controller layer.
I am confused about it, and could not find anything on the internet

For e.g I have the following controller definition:

```
@GetMapping("/Client")
public ResponseEntity<List<Client>> getAllClients(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            @RequestParam(value = McsConstants.PAGE_HEADER, required = false) Integer page,
            @RequestParam(value = McsConstants.SIZE_HEADER, required = false) Integer size) {...}
```

And the valid request would be

```
GET .../Client
GET .../Client?page=1
GET .../Client?size=10
GET .../Client?page=1&size=10
```

How can I validate the case when I have an undefined request param like below?

```
GET .../Client?someUndefinedParam=1
```

Let me know please for any ideas or links

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this can be using @RequestParam annotation on a Map or MultiValueMap argument.

The map is populated with all the request parameters, therein you can write your logic to validate and reject unidentified query params.

**EDIT:** Following is an example for the same-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void testMethod(@RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams) {
    if (!isValidParams(allRequestParams)) { 
         // isValidParams() will validate the map with a reference map containing all the expected params
         // throw BadRequestException here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! do you have an example on how to use a map with request param?

Comment: Sure, I'll add that in the answer..give me a few minutes.

Comment: Example added!!

Comment: If this helped you, would request you to accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look a little bit later

Comment: That's great news!

Answer (score 0):

let me share my knowledge it may helpful for some other scenarios

If the requestparam and variable is same name you no need to mention the value @RequestParam .

below i have mentioned with code example. Please share ur feedback

```
@GetMapping("/Client")
public ResponseEntity<List<Client>> getAllClients(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        @RequestParam <Optional>Integer page,
        @RequestParam <Optional>Integer size) {
         //you can do ur logics 
       }
```